# Mongoose populate, execPopulate not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose model of 'Department' and another one of 'Course'. A one to many relation. Saving department id under department field in course document. I want to query all the departments and populate all their courses in one request. 
Here is the code for course schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
name:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
 department:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Department'
    }
module.exports = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema)
```

Heres the code for Department

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const validator = require('validator')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
admin: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        trim: true,
    }
departmentSchema.virtual('courses',{
    ref: 'Course',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'department'
})
const Department = mongoose.model(' Department',departmentSchema)

module.exports = Department
```

Here is the route for getting all the departments

```
router.get('/departments', async (req, res)=>{
    Department.find().populate('courses').exec(function (err, departments) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
        res.status(200).send(departments)
    })
})
```

this code returns just departments without populating the courses array.

Comment: execPopulate() has been removed in mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the solution on the mongoose documentation. Apparently 'virtuals are not included in toJSON() output by default. If you want populate virtuals to show up when using functions that rely on JSON.stringify(), like Express' res.json() function, set the virtuals: true option on your schema's toJSON options.'
so I modified my department schema to look like this

```
const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    admin: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        trim: true,
        ref: 'User'
    }

},{
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: {virtuals: true}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
    name: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
    },

    email: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
    },

    cart: {
      items: [
        {
          productId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Product",
            require: true,
          },

          quantity: {
            type: Number,
            require: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },

  // becuase the execPopulate() doens't work 
  //.. we fix the issue with this code addition
  // !!! execPopulate() function was removed from mongoose db !!!

  {  timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true } }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `execPopulation()`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following old courses of Node JS, you will always get this error.
Because at that time .populate() method was not returning Promise to chain .then() method with it, what we were doing is that we would chain .execPopulate() method along with .populate() to chain .then() method on it.

So in order to work with .populate() correctly, just remove .execPopulate() because mongoose is no longer using it.

```
req.user
.populate("cart.items.productId")
.then((user) => {
  console.log(user);
  const products = user.cart.items;
  res.render("shop/cart", {
    path: "/cart",
    pageTitle: "Your Cart",
    products: products,
  });
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```